# JQuery render partial with nice fade in/out effect?

Tags: jquery, render, fadeout

I've got this:

```
$('#yummyCakeOptions').html("<%=j render partial: 'icings', locals: { icings: @icings }%>");
```

Any way to put a nice transition effect on that?

I have tried `.fade_in()` `.fade_out()` `show(slow)` `.hide().fadeIn(4000)` in various places in the line, all break it

Comment: What do you mean by "all break it" ?

Comment: all cause the jquery to cease functioning

Comment: Maybe you should show more of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make transition effect, you can use callback of [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) function then you change content of your object and do fadeIn() to show it.

```js
$('#yummyCakeOptions').fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $(this).html("<%=j render partial: 'icings', locals: { icings: @icings }%>").fadeIn();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="yummyCakeOptions">Test</div>
```